# mongodb aggregation group $push

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this code:

```
{
    _id: {
      "$push": "$category.name" 
    }
}
```

but when I run this, then it errors:

```
invalid operator $push
```

Comment: Can you use the [edit] link to show us the full aggregation pipeline, some sample documents and the expected output? Depending on what kind of aggregate you are after, you need the group key as `_id` separate from the accumulated fields i.e. the `$group` pipeline should have the following structure `{ '_id': '$key', 'categories': { '$push': '$category.name' } }`

Answer (score 2):

its bad way to use $push in $group (_id field) , $group (_id field) is used to group the data in collection so $push is invalid operator in "_id field"
so only you getting this error

$push use this way

this is my data

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "abc", "price" : 10, "quantity" : 2, "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T08:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "jkl", "price" : 20, "quantity" : 1, "date" : ISODate("2014-02-03T09:00:00Z") }

db.sales.aggregate([
 {
   $group:
     {
       _id: { day: { $dayOfYear: "$date"}},
       itemsSold: { $push:  { item: "$item"} }
     }
 }])
```